# Actionbar activity and fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using an ActioBarActivity in order to use the new toolbar from appcompact v21.
But, when using this type of activity, when I replace a fragment with de parameter addToBackStack(), it doesn't work.
When the user presses the back button, the role activity is destroyed.

This is my onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar,getSupportActionBar());
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, ListaFragment.newInstance(""))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And this is the click that replaces the fragment

```
@Override
public void helpClick(int stringResource) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, HelpFragment.newInstance(stringResource))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

I don't know if there is an compability erro when using the import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity with the import android.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. You should use classes from the support library: `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of default ones.

So you have to replace `getFragmentManager()` with the `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `import android.app.Fragment;` with `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

Also your fragments should extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class.